# What is the fastest way to get the Diggle Nog achievement?

Tags: achievements, dungeons-of-dredmor

The Diggle Nog! achievement states:

> Diggle Nog! - Make some Diggle Nog. Who doesn't love a nice cold glass of Diggle Nog?

Since I've never played this game, I have no idea what to do to get it.  What is the fastest/easiest way of doing it?

Comment: If you have the game, you can look up the crafting recipe for it; they're all stored in xml files in a subfolder off of the main game folder. Just do a text search for "diggle nog" in crafts.xml IIRC (I would do it myself but I'm not at my home computer).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This took me about 20 minutes of play to achieve (although I've played the game plenty before, so know how it all works), so it should be fairly straight forward to achieve even if you're new to the game.

If you look at [the wiki](http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Diggle_Nog) (or the [XML file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CVP3V.png), or the in-game crafting menu) you will see that Diggle Nog can be crafted using a **Porta-Still** and combination of **Aqua Vitae**, a **Diggle Egg** and some **Grog**.

Therefore, to get the achievement you need to find all three craft items and a Porta-Still to combine them with. Craft them together and that's your achievement.

So, to minimize the time to get this achievement I'd *highly* recommend starting with the [Alchemy](http://www.dredmorwiki.com/wiki/Alchemy) skill so that you start with some *Aqua Vitae* (which will probably be in your quick bar, not your inventory) and a *Porta-Still*. You'll then need to find the other two items yourself, but they're fairly common items that you should be able to find somewhere on the first level.

Keep on the lookout for Drink Machines:

[image]

If you take **Burglary** as a skill, you can steal random liquor from drink machines, which may speed up your acquisition of the Grog.  Otherwise, check each one you find to see if they're selling any.

Diggle Eggs are found frequently in Diggle Nests, which are small rooms containing a couple of Diggles and usually nests filled with eggs:

[image]

Comment: Note I've made a grace-period edit (had the wrong crafting tool).

Comment: I'm pretty sure one of the magic skill trees spawns you with some grog, but I might be wrong about that.  I was playing my "mage" who's still on the first level of the dungeon, and I loaded the save and I had all three items, so they're really easy to find.

Comment: @agent86, good to know.

Comment: Let me add something: Aqua Vitae can be crafted by distilling most alcoholic drinks in the still. No matter how many times I started as Alchemist, I never got Aqua Vitae from the off. You'll need to buy some alcohol and distill it.

Comment: @finalsin I started with one when I tagged alchemist, I didn't see it in my inventory though, but it was there when I was crafting

Comment: @finalsin: I'm pretty sure that you do.

Comment: @yx.: Did you check your quick-use bar-thing on the bottom left? That's where mine was.

Comment: While [DMA57361's answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/42864/126) is quite good, I thought I would add my own two bits: Getting grog is quite random. As far as I can tell, it cannot be guaranteed as a starting item, but it does come sometime. It appears as if the weapon skills have a chance of including it from the start. Alchemy gives you some vitae, so all you'd need to find is a diggle egg.

Comment: I ended up just buying it from a drink vendor, those are quite common.  The diggle egg took me the longest

Comment: @DMA57361, hope you don't mind my edits.  I put together a couple of screenshots yesterday.

Comment: I got the achievement after finding a Diggle egg in a food vendor, so make sure you check those as well.

Comment: Fine with me @agent86 :)